# How to import JSON data into EXCEL columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power-query, json

I have an excel spreadsheet like following:

[image]

with a first column the name of something, and then two columns "date" and "owner". I also have the following JSON file which I want to import via "Get Data" -> "From File" -> "From JSON" to populate the empty columns automatically from the data in the JSON file.

JSON file content:

```
{
    "TEST-1": {
        "date": 2,
        "owner": "Alfred"
    },
    "TEST-2": {
        "date": 4,
        "owner": "Berta"
    },
    "TEST-3": {
        "date": 6,
        "owner": "Cesar"
    },
    "TEST-42": {
        "date": 84,
        "owner": "Dave"
    },
}
```

in the end I want to have the excel table look like following:

[image]

But I have no clue on how to do this with this "Power Query".
Any ideas? Tutorials? Simple explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in 3 parts.

**A. Part 1**

1. Select the range. Go to Data -> Get Data -> From Table/Range. Select my table has headers. Click OK.
2. Power query editor opens. Close and Save.

[image: Table after using Power Query]

**B. Part 2**

1. Go to Data -> Get Data -> From File -> From JSON. This will be the output

[image: Json data imported to Power Query]

2. Go to Convert -> To Into Table

[image: Converted data to table]

3. Click on the arrow next to Value. Select the items to show. Click OK.

[image: Value selection]

4. The image below will be the result. Right click on the column header, select Rename to change the column name. This will be the output. Close and save.

[image: Renamed columms]

**C. Part 3**

1. Go to Data -> Get Data -> Combine Queries -> Merge
2. When Power Query Editor opens, set the first table, then the data from the json file as the second table. Select the columns from both tables that will be the basis of the merge. On Join Kind listbox, select "Left outer (all from first, matching from second)"

[image: Tables and columns selection - Merge window]

3. Expand the arrow from the last column. Select the columns whose values must be displayed, click OK.

[image: Columns selections]

This will be the result.

[image: Result after columns' selection]

4. Remove unnecessary columns and rename (if necessary) others.

[image: Result after removing and renaming columns]

5. Close and save.

Comment: so you can only import the whole json file, not based on what you have already in your spreadsheet?

Comment: I think it is possible. How many rows do you have in your real file? I am asking because it might take more steps (2 different tables/connections, then merging them).

Comment: @Alex I have edited the answer and added steps to combine the table and the json file.

Answer (score 0):

1. I have a file that's a log file where each row is its own json object, but had to enclose the whole file inside "[" (prefixed to first line) and "]" (postfixed to last line), and append a "," to every line (except the last), effectively to create a single array in order for the json import to run. Is there an option to treat each line/row as a separate json object?
2. Some of the fields in each json line are themselves an array, but I want to have these broken out into new columns rather than new rows. When I try the alternative and specify a delimiter, i.e. ":", it shows "Error" for every row. Is there a way to expand such arrays into new columns so that the data imported into the resulting table still has 1 row per input (log) line?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).